# How to construct a confidence interval for p-value

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value

I have a simple query regarding the construction of a confidence interval for a p-value. How do I construct such a confidence interval? Like we construct a C.I. for **t-value** ($\bar{X} \pm t \times(s/ \sqrt{n})$), can such kind of intervals be created for **p-value**?

I think (not completely sure) such C.I. for p-value is called **replication interval**. I tried googling but couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/250269

Comment: Also related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/258143/estimating-population-p-value-pi-using-an-observed-p-value?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: This question needs more background and details.  It implies a setting in which (a) there is a true but unknown p-value and (b) somehow you are estimating that p-value with uncertainty.

Comment: @whuber. Is there ever a "true but unknown p-value"? I don't think so. A p-value is an assessment of  a particular data set and null H. I can't think of a situation where there is a true (population) value.

Comment: This question was asked before (so is a duplicate) of this one (with good answers):    https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/254595/what-is-the-confidence-interval-of-a-p-value

Comment: @Harvey Yes! Bootstrapping is the standard example.  There will be a specific p-value for the bootstrap statistic, but except for the smallest datasets it's never computed: it is only estimated through resampling.

Answer (score 8):

One constructs a confidence interval for a parameter of interest whose true value is unknown (the parameter is related to properties of the population). 95% of 95% confidence intervals contain the true value for the parameter.

A p-value, on the other hand, is an outcome of a random variable (its value depends on the sample). It makes no sense to speak of a confidence interval for a p-value, since it does not represent a parameter of unknown value. There is no such thing as the true p-value for a population.

Perhaps your question is asking about the distribution of p-values. For the non-discrete case, the p-value distribution is uniform [0-1], if the null hypothesis is correct.

Comment: +1. Since OP mentioned "replication interval", this question (so far unanswered) might be relevant: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/250269

Comment: @amoeba Lots of helpful answers now about the distribution of possible p-values (different than confidence intervals) in that link.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating confidence interval for p-value is a valid approach when you use the Monte Carlo simulation to obtain p-value (e.g., in R when you choose simulate.p.value=TRUE for chi-square test). In this case, p-value varies, so you may need to use, e.g., 99% C.I. To find out more please see C.R. Mehta and N.R. Patel, Exact tests, SPSS inc., 2012. How to calculate this in R, you may see an example in the following paper: https://rdcu.be/dpz18.

Comment: I don't think "confidence interval" is the right term to use for your approach. I believe you are making assumptions about variation, setting a sample size, and simulating many data sets. Then you can present a range of possible p-values. That can be useful, but is quite distinct from a confidence interval (as @dean wrote) that is trying to predict the uncertainty with which you know a population paramter.

Comment: @Harvey I believe this answer might reflect a different interpretation of the question than yours.  It looks like a correct and helpful response subject to the conditions laid out in the first sentence.

Comment: @whuber It is all a matter of terminology. Calculating that interval is definitely helpful. But it seems more like a prediction interval rather than a confidence interval.  Picky maybe, but using terminology correctly is needed for clear communication.