# Estimate confidence intervals for the P value of the Pearson's Chi-squared test

Tags: r, p-value, inference, simulation, contingency-tables

I have a contingency table where I estimate the p value Pearson's Chi-squared test, I want to take a confidence interval to validate this value P
some code to do this by simulation monte carlo?

```
       A   B   C   D   
  H    3   9  16  13  
  M   13   8  19  21 



  Pearson's Chi-squared test
   data:  tabla1
X-squared = 4.7077, df = 3, p-value = 0.1945
```

Comment: This looks like a question about R code, which is off-topic here. Can you reformulate as a question about statistics or methodology?

Comment: CI of what estimate? The p-value? This is not done.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are asking about how to construct a confidence interval for the p-value (from a chisquared test). But confidence intervals are constructed for *parameters*, and the p-value is not a parameter. So a confidence interval for the p-value does not make sense.

Further discussion is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248524/how-to-construct-a-confidence-interval-for-p-value).